# Can't make Pop() in flutter because retrieve image links from API in the Parent screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

The app crashes when I make a pop(); because of I display an images form API in the parent screen(that's what I call it).
I know the reason is the images link from API but I can't find a solution for that.

[Here,beause I used a specific link image, it works:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7QfL.png)

[And when I used a link image from API, the app crashes when I navigate:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijCXp.png)

[And this is the search screen:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoQZm.png)

Thank you in advance.

....................

Comment: It's very hard to help, with the data you provided. Please check out the guidelines how to ask a question. add error log, add minimal code to the question instead of pictures, etc...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.